# Trying to update prices of 30.000 products using php and MySql

Tags: php, mysql

I do not have much experience with mysql. I'm trying to write a small php program that allows me to update the prices of more products, contained in a mysql table, in the most efficient way, taking data from another table that contains the updated prices. This operation must be done every morning and if possible, without stressing the server.

This is the scenario...

I have two tables that have the value "post_id" in common.
In the first table, the "post_id" is entered as a unique value, while in the second table, the same "post_id" is present in various rows.
The "app" table contains the data I use in the application and the second "updates", is updated every morning with the current prices, using the "LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE" function.
The "app" table contains about 30,000 rows, while the "updates" table has about 80,000, this is because each row of this table contains the price of a single product (apple, pear, peach, etc ..)

What I need is to take the prices of the various products that have the same "post_id" from the "updates" table and build the mysql query that will update the prices of each product in the "app" table.

This is table "app"

```
+----+---------+---------+---------+---------+----------+-----+
| id | post_id | p_apple |  p_pear | p_peach | p_banana | upd |
+----+---------+---------+---------+---------+----------+-----+
| 1  |  22476  |  1.234  |  1.345  |  1.456  | 1.641    |  0  |
| 2  |  32993  |  1.235  |  1.641  |  1.343  | 1.266    |  0  | 
| 3  |  11328  |  1.678  |  1.879  |  1.434  | 1.856    |  0  | 
| 4  |  34651  |  1.777  |  1.445  |  1.274  | 1.346    |  0  | 
+----+---------+---------+---------+---------+----------+-----+
```

And this is table "updates"

```
+----+---------+---------+---------+
| id | post_id |  fruits |  price  |
+----+---------+---------+---------+
| 1  |  22476  |  apple  |  1.345  |
| 2  |  22476  |  peach  |  1.641  |
| 3  |  22476  |  pear   |  1.335  |
| 4  |  22476  |  banana |  1.445  |
| 5  |  32993  |  pear   |  1.675  |
| 6  |  32993  |  banana |  1.465  |
| 7  |  11328  |  pear   |  1.445  |
| 8  |  11328  |  peach  |  1.443  |
| 9  |  11328  |  banana |  1.445  |
| 10 |  34651  |  apple  |  1.454  |
| 11 |  34651  |  peach  |  1.445  |
| 12 |  34651  |  banana |  1.879  |
+----+---------+---------+---------+
```

I created a small function to help me build the update query

```
function buildquery($type,$price){

    if($type == "apple"){
        $query = "p_apple ='".$price."', ";
    }
    elseif($type == "peach"){
        $query = "p_peach ='".$price."', ";
    }
    elseif($type == "pear"){
        $query = "p_pear ='".$price."', ";      
    }
    elseif($type == "banana"){
        $query = "p_banana ='".$price."', ";        
    }
    
    return $query;
}
```

extracting the "post_id" value from the "app" table

```
$query = "SELECT `id`, `post_id` FROM app WHERE `updated` = 0 ORDER BY `post_id` LIMIT 1";

if ($res = $mysqli->query($query)) {    
    $row   = $res->fetch_assoc();
    $myid  = $row['id'];
    $mypid = $row['post_id'];
} else {
    echo("Error description: ".$mysqli->error);
}
```

count the rows that have the same "post_id" and extract the updated data. This from the "updates" table

```
$query2 = "SELECT *, COUNT(post_id) as nr FROM `updates` WHERE `post_id` = $mypid";
if ($result = $mysqli->query($query2)) {
    $rows = $resu->fetch_assoc();
    $nr   = $rows['nr'];
    
    $query3 = "UPDATE `app` SET ";  // start building the mysql query to update prices in table "app"
    
    for($i=0;$i<$nr;$i++){
        $myid2   = $rows['id'];
        $mypid2  = $rows['post_id'];
        $fruit   = $rows['fruits'];
        $price   = $rows['price'];  
        $query3 .= buildquery($fruit,$price);  
    }
    echo $query3;  // I've come this far, but this approach doesn't work.
}
```

in the end for each "post_id" I would need to get a result like this:

```
UPDATE app SET `p_apple` = "1.345", `p_peach` = "1.641", `p_pear` = "1.335", `p_banana` = "1.445", upd = 1 WHERE `post_id` = 22476;
UPDATE app SET `p_pear` = "1.675", `p_banana` = "1.456", upd = 1 WHERE `post_id` = 32993;
UPDATE app SET `p_pear` = "1.445", `p_peach` = "1.443", `p_banana` = "1.445", upd = 1 WHERE `post_id` = 11328;  
UPDATE app SET `p_apple` = "1.454", `p_peach` = "1.445", `p_banana` = "1.879", upd = 1 WHERE `post_id` = 34651; 
UPDATE app SET  .....
UPDATE app SET  .....
```

This for about 30.000 rows

Can you suggest me the most correct way to accomplish what i need? Thank you

Comment: It would be best if you redesigned the first table, so that you didn't have all the `p_XXX` columns. Do it similarly to the `updates` table, with each fruit in a different row.

Comment: Use `UPDATE+JOIN` rather than 30,000 `UPDATE` statements.

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot redesign the app table. Thank you for your suggestion.

Comment: *"I'm trying to write a small php program that allows me to update the prices of more products, contained in a mysql table"* ... It would be easier, since you want a "relative" price change, to *not* change the db itself, and instead have a setting for the relative price change.

Comment: i would write a procedure with a loop over al update table rows and use dynamic sql to update all columns. the you don't need to make this massive php code

Answer (score 0):

Use conditional updates in a `JOIN`.

```
UPDATE app AS a
JOIN updates AS u ON a.post_id = u.post_id
SET a.p_apple = IF(u.fruit = 'apple', u.price, a.p_apple),
    a.p_banana = IF(u.fruit = 'banana', u.price, a.p_banana),
    a.p_pear = IF(u.fruit = 'pear', u.price, a.p_pear),
    a.p_peach = IF(u.fruit = 'peach', u.price, a.p_peach)
```

Comment: @Barman's answer solved my problem very well. The query he suggested works perfectly and runs on about 90,000 records in seconds.. Thank you